# Two docked components where the second fills the remaining space

Tags: java, swing, layout

I'm working on a board game and I'd like the board to be a square docked West with dimension frameHeight x frameHeight, and I'd like the sidepanel which is docked East to fill the remaining with.

Essentially:
West - frameHeight x frameHeight
East - remainingWidth x frameHeight

```
 _________________
|          |      |
|          |      |
|  WEST    | EAST |
|          |      |
|          |      |
|__________|______|
```

Using MigLayout at the moment I'm saying LARGE (west)'s height should be 100% but I'm not sure how to say width should equal 100% of parent height and have SMALL (east) fill the remaining width.

Anyone with a decent idea to approach this?

Comment: Don't you mean "West - frameWidth x frameHeight"?

Comment: No, the width should be the height - ie. a square.

Comment: How is the extra space assigned re height?  ASCII art of the GUI in 'smallest' and 'bigger WxH' would be very handy at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MiGLayout won't let you use references for size constraints, but you can do it with the `pos` constraint:

```
add(panel, "id large, pos 0 0 container.h container.h");
```

This will add `panel` seemingly docked to the left edge, covering the entire height and with a width equal to its height.

You could then fill the remaining space with:

```
add(otherPanel, "pos large.x2 0 container.w container.h");
```

Comment: Where do I set the id for the container though?

Comment: @paranoid-android It's an automatic id set by MiGLayout :D

Comment: @paranoid-android No problem :) I edited the constraints, they're more idiomatic now (though functionally equivalent)

Answer (score 1):

1. in the case that `DockingPanel` can covering part of `JFrame` (with funcionality for show and hide) then to use

   - `GlassPane` (notice all `JComponents` must be `lightweight`, otherwise `GlassPane` is gone to behind)
   - `JLayer` (based of Java6 `JXLayer`)
2. most confortable could be to use `JSplitPane`

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `getPreferredSize()` method to caclulate the size of the panel based on it's parent's size.  Keep in mind at this point you're completely ignoring the size of any content in the panel.  If you still care about that, I'd recommend extending a `JScrollPane` instead of a `JPanel`.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TempProject extends JPanel{

    enum Type{
        SQUARE,
        FILL
    };

    Type mytype;

    public TempProject(Type type){
        mytype = type;
        if(mytype == Type.SQUARE){
            setBackground(Color.orange);
        } else if(mytype == Type.FILL){
            setBackground(Color.blue);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
        Dimension result = getParent().getSize();
        if(mytype == Type.SQUARE){
            //Calculate square size
            result.width = result.height;

        } else if(mytype == Type.FILL){
            //Calculate fill size
            int tempWidth = result.width - result.height;
            if(tempWidth > 0){  // Ensure width stays greater than 0
                result.width = tempWidth;
            } else{
                result.width = 0;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    JFrame f = new JFrame("Java Game");
                    f.setSize(700, 500);
                    f.setVisible(true);
                    f.setBackground(Color.GRAY);

                    Box contentPanel = Box.createHorizontalBox();
                    contentPanel.add(new TempProject(Type.SQUARE));
                    contentPanel.add(new TempProject(Type.FILL));
                    f.setContentPane(contentPanel);

                    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

    }

}
```